# OData - filter by nested property

Tags: odata

does anyone know how to express an OData $filter against a nested property?

for ex. I have the following Atom entry,

```
<entry>
...
 <m:properties>
...
  <d:RegardingObjectId m:type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.EntityReference">
  <d:Id m:type="Edm.Guid">3f3712fd-fc49-e211-8eb8-000c296272c8</d:Id> 
  <d:LogicalName>new_sportsleague</d:LogicalName> 
  <d:Name>Boca</d:Name> 
  </d:RegardingObjectId>
```

I want to filter for those entries that have RegardingObjectId/LogicalName eq 'new_sportsleague'.

Tried with 'RegardingObjectId/LogicalName' and 'RegardingObjectId.LogicalName' with no luck.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`'RegardingObjectId/LogicalName'` would be the correct syntax.

For example:

http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers

returns two results, whereas

http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Suppliers?$filter=Address/Street eq 'NE 228th'

returns just one.

I don't see a place in the OData spec that explicitly states whether filtering using properties of a complex value is legal or not, but it seems that WCF Data Services supports it. It could be that other OData implementations don't.

Comment: You are right Jen... It seems that Dynamics CRM 2011 doesn't support such queries. When querying against a complex type I'm getting $exception {"Reference to property LogicalName on complex type EntityReference is not supported"} System.Exception {Microsoft.Crm.CrmNotSupportedException} :-(

Answer (score 6):

Use following odata API example to access nested properties with filter data

```
http://192.168.50.152:50086/odata/StationOperationLogs/?$expand=ProductionStation,ProductionStation/ProductionUnit&$filter=ProductionStation/ProductionUnit/Id eq 2
```

Comment: this is not working for me. .../IB?$expand=Organization&$filter=Organization/OrganizationId eq '2' error is ""Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a property access of a property 'OrganizationId' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.""